# Extracting Values Not Working JSON file?

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in java programming. I am trying to get Instagram users full name. and below is my code

```
package gibs.smith.testapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private String name = "";
    private String link ="";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url= new URL("https://instagram.com/priya.p.varrier/?__a=1");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line !=null){
                line =bufferedReader.readLine();           
                JSONObject jo= new JSONObject(line);
                JSONObject user=jo.getJSONObject("user");
                name=user.getString("full_name");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity.data.setText(this.name);
    }
}
```

but it is not working. it dose not extracts the string value "full_name". 
It is retrieving the `JSON` file but not the desired value. 
The URL is `https://instagram.com/priya.p.varrier/?__a=1`

any help would be great.

----Edit-----
adding graphql object causes app crash and below is catlog output
here is the log 
https://justpaste.it/1itsa

Comment: try https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: You are not passing your ' name ' value to your 'onPostExecute'. Instead of Void try sending 'String name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the bug. It must be NullPointerException.

```
    while (line !=null)
```

it will run until line = null. Then this line will give you the exception.

```
    new JSONObject(line);
```

and you shoud get the **graphql** first.

so the solution should look like this.

```
if(line != null) {
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(line);
    JSONObject graphql = jo.getJSONObject("graphql");
    JSONObject user = graphql.getJSONObject("user");
    name = user.getString("full_name");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hinte sir !

Answer (score 0):

As per your JSON 
your `full_name` key is inside `user` JSONObject which is inside `graphql` JSONObject.

So to get the full_name value you have to first retrieve `graphql` JSONObject.

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(line);
JSONObject graphqlObj = jo.getJSONObject("graphql");
JSONObject user = jographqlObj.getJSONObject("user");
name=user.getString("full_name");
```

You can use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to check JSON structure of your file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've already tried this but after adding graphql object the app is crashing.

Comment: If the app is crashing then check Log and find out what's the exception and in which line you are getting the exception.

Comment: here is the log https://justpaste.it/1itsa and what i see is error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`